# Dart encoding hex using Base64

Tags: dart, base64, encode

I need to encode this

> "f08b3616d575acffc9c9493a888eb4f915a6830f94101363ba01fc7c42011789"

to this

> "8Is2FtV1rP/JyUk6iI60+RWmgw+UEBNjugH8fEIBF4k="

using dart and base64 encode. I used this tool
[base64 encode](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base64_encode.html)

[image: details]

If it helps I manage to do it on Python using this oneliner

```
s = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()
```

but have no clue for the equivalent in dart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hex codec isn't in the core `dart:convert` but is buried in a package also called `convert`. So, add `convert` to your `pubspec.yaml`, and then:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

void main() {
  final h = 'f08b3616d575acffc9c9493a888eb4f915a6830f94101363ba01fc7c42011789';
  final b = base64.encode(hex.decode(h));
  print(b);
}
```